# I want to create a global service for the entire application

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an application and I have the following question. I have thought about creating a service that calls all services to centralize all calls. My idea is that this service has several public variables from which the other screens can obtain the data by calling it as a subscriber for example. I want that when another screen obtains this data they are equally updated and so that each screen does not have to make the same call to the same service, in the background centralize, and that if there is any change in the services called, the service updates the variables of the called services. This is possible? or I am getting confused in the way of using the services ?, if it is not possible ... How can I make these variables change dynamically when I update those services that are within the service? How can I call those variables of the service and keep me updated within that screen? Is there a way to do it? Thank you!!

Comment: Angular services are singleton, so only one time the service object is created. If you add your service in the root, you can consume it from anywhere when you need. From angular 4+, when you create a service by cli, it makes the service available to root  `providedIn: 'root'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible and is the normal way that services behave in Angular. Services are created as singletons depending on where you `provide` them. Providing the service at the root level ensures that all components that inject this service will receive the same reference, not a new instance. This is done by passing metadata into the `@Injectable` decorator.

Let's create a service, provide it at the root level, and inject it into two components. Each component will receive the same reference. If we add an observable to the service, and both components subscribe to it, they are receiving the same values. When that value changes, it will be updated in both components.

Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  public message$: Observable<string>;
  private message: BehaviorSubject<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.message = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
    this.message$ = this.message.asObservable();
  }

  public updateMessage(message: string): void {
    this.message.next(message);
  }
}
```

Components (they are *almost* exactly the same as each other):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-first-component',
  template: `
    <p>first component: {{ message$ | async }}</p>
  `
})
export class MyFirstComponent implements OnInit {
  public message$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message$ = this.myService.message$;
    this.myService.updateMessage('new message')
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-second-component',
  template: `
    <p>second component: {{ message$ | async }}</p> 
  `
})
export class MySecondComponent implements OnInit {
  public message$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message$ = this.myService.message$;
  }
}
```

If you look in the templates of the two components, we are subscribing to the observable in the service, and displaying the message. The messages defaults to `'default message'`, as set by the service.

Notice that in the `ngOnInit` in the first component, we update the message on this line: `this.myService.updateMessage('new message')`. Take note that this is only in the first component, but not the second component. If you ran this in an app, the message would update on both components to `'new message'`. This shows that this is the same instance of `MyService` and can be used and updated by any number of components.